# Installing RcppArmadillo in R

Tags: r, rcpparmadillo

i'm having this error when trying to install `RcppArmadillo` in R, and is driving me crazy, i've not been able to find how to deal with it:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcppArmadillo’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/Ghost/Rlibs/00LOCK-RcppArmadillo/00new/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so':
  dlopen(/Users/Ghost/Rlibs/00LOCK-RcppArmadillo/00new/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so, 6): Symbol not found: _wrapper2_ddot_
  Referenced from: /Users/Ghost/Rlibs/00LOCK-RcppArmadillo/00new/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/Ghost/Rlibs/00LOCK-RcppArmadillo/00new/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so
Error: loading failed
```

Any insights/advice on how to fix it?

Comment: Remove your system installation of Armadillo. Within your setup it seems to be interfering with RcppArmadillo.  You do not need to install Armadillo in order to use RcppArmadillo.

Comment: Will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Nope, i reinstalled `armadillo` and exactly the same error..

Comment: No, you need to completely uninstall armadillo. Do it manually.  Armadillo and RcppArmadillo are related yet two distinct things. They seem to be interfering with each other on your system, so remove one of them.

Comment: Sorry mate, i misread. I uninstalled armadillo and worked flawlessly!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Something is not quite right with your setup. As a possible workaround, define `ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER` before including RcppArmadillo in your code.

```
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
```